# Why onClick function is not adding class to my div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Here I am trying to add class name to div through javascript using onClick function but it is not working . The console.log() is printing the message that means the function is being called but adding of class to div is not working . Please tell me the reason where I am doing wrong.

This is javascript code

```
 <script>

  function showLoginForm(){
    document.getElementById('overlay').classList.add("showOverlay");
    document.getElementById('popUpForm').classList.add("showpopUpForm");

    console.log("Hello, world!");
    
  }

 // console.log("Hello, world!");
  var loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn');

  loginBtn.addEventListener("click",showLoginForm);
</script>
```

This is my html button

```
 <li><button id="loginBtn" >LOGIN</button></li>
```

This is my pop div on which I am adding classes

```
  <div id="overlay">
</div>

<div id="popUpForm">
  
      <div id="headTexts">
        <h1>Welcome back !</h1>
        <h3>Please enter your login details</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="btns">
        <button id="popLoginBtn">Login</button>
       
      </div>

      <div id="loginForm">
          
          <input type="text" name="" id="nameText" placeholder="phone" class="popInput">
          <input type="password" name="" id="paswText" placeholder="Password" 
  class="popInput">

          <input type="submit" value="Login" id="userLoginBtn">
      </div>
<div id="signupBox">
<p>Please enter your login details</p>
<button id="popSignupBtn">Signup</button>
</div>

</div>
```

This is my css code

```
 #overlay {
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -100;
transition: 0.5s;
opacity: 0;
}

 .showOverlay {
z-index: 1000;
opacity: 1;
background-color: red;
 }

   #popUpForm {
position: fixed;
height: auto;
width: auto;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: white;
z-index: 110;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: start;
justify-content: center;
padding: 2vw;
opacity: 0;
top: -50%;
transition: 2s;
  }

.showpopUpForm {
top: 50%;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1100;
}

#popLoginBtn {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: white;
color: black;
border: 0.15vw solid black;
padding: 0.8vw;
border-radius: 0.3vw;
margin-right: 0.5vw;
transition: 0.4s;
width: 10vw;
}

#popLoginBtn:hover {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}

 #popSignupBtn {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: black;
color: white;
border: 0.15vw solid black;
padding: 0.5vw;
border-radius: 0.3vw;
transition: 0.4s;
width: 10vw;
font-size: 1.1vw;
margin-top: 0.7vw;
 }

 #popSignupBtn:hover {
background-color: red;
color: white;
 }

  #btns {
margin-top: 2vw;
margin-bottom: 2vw;
display: none;
}

   #loginForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
align-items: start;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 3vw;
 }

 .popInput {
width: 25vw;
padding: 0.5vw;
font-size: 1vw;
border: 0.1vw solid black;
border-radius: 0.3vw;
margin-top: 0.8vw;
}

 #userLoginBtn {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: rgb(0, 255, 162);
color: black;
border: 0.15vw solid rgb(0, 255, 162);
padding: 0.5vw;
border-radius: 0.3vw;
margin-top: 1vw;
transition: 0.4s;
width: 8vw;
font-size: 1.1vw;
}

  #userLoginBtn:hover {
background-color: red;
border: 0.15vw solid red;
color: white;
 }

 #signupBox {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: start;
justify-content: start;
margin-top: 3vw;
 }
```

I have provided only the targeted part of code as the full code was very long . If any body wants to see the full code then please let me know in the comment box

Comment: If by any chance that `<script>` bloc is in the header you'd need a listener `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myInitFunction)` to wait for the page to render before trying to grab `#loginBtn`

Comment: @savageGoat You are right, but they said the console.log is working which means the event is working

Comment: Function is being called as console is working

Answer (score 3):

You have set the `href` attribute on your link to an empty string, this will result in it linking to the current page. Every time you are clicking your link the page reloads.

To prevent the default behaviour of following the link when you click it, you must use `.preventDefault()` on the Event that is passed to your event listener (`showLoginForm`)

```
function showLoginForm(e) { //add 'e' as the first argument
    
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the default behaviour of the event
    
    document.getElementById('overlay').classList.add("showOverlay");
    document.getElementById('popUpForm').classList.add("showpopUpForm");

    console.log("Hello, world!");

}
```

Comment: sorry I have removed it now .. it was a mistake but still it is not working

Comment: Additionally, `href` could point to the same page with a `#ID` link

Comment: I have removed it

Comment: but still it is not working

Comment: Hmmm yeah if you are using a <button> instead <a> then the href shouldn't be the issue. Have you confirmed the classes are not being applied (inspect the element and check it's class attribute) or are you just assuming they aren't being applied because you can't see any difference? It might be that the styles being applied have a lower priority (being targetted at classes) than the original style (targetted at IDs)

Comment: @NandiniSriavastava Did you check by inspect element, if the css classes are added or not. I checked and find that the classes are added. You need to check your css style.

Comment: It is solved now .. I forgot the selector specificity rule of css . Thanks for our concern

Answer (score 3):

Your .showOverlay and .showpopUpForm classes are not working you should override the css like this hopefully it will work

```css
#popUpForm.showpopUpForm {
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1100;
}

#overlay.showOverlay {
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. I was thrown because the question stated 'adding of class to div is not working' when it actually is working, just not having a visible effect due to selector specificity.

Comment: @nandini-sriavastava please set this answer as solution if it solves the issue